# Creating a Bookmark Handler for eww

Tags: eww

I'm attempting to create a bookmark handler for eww so I can use Emacs's
built-in bookmarks to save and visit urls with eww.

There's an equivenant setup for w3m here: https://github.com/TotalView/dotemacs/blob/master/.emacs.d/elpa/w3m-20140330.1933/bookmark-w3m.el

From what I can gather I need to:

- Create a function to actually make a properly formatted bookmark entry.
- Find a way to grab all the data you need to create the bookmark from eww.
- Set bookmark-make-record-function to that function.
- Make a bookmark 'handler' which launches eww with the bookmark's url.

So far I've got the following setup. However, I'm getting the error `oht-eww-bookmark-make-record: Symbol’s value as variable is void: oht-eww-current-title`

```lisp
(defun oht-eww-current-title ()
  "Returns the title of the current eww buffer"
  (plist-get eww-data :title))

(defun oht-eww-bookmark-make-record ()
  "Return a bookmark record for the current eww buffer."
  (interactive)
  `(,oht-eww-current-title
    (location . ,eww-current-url)
    (handler . ,oht-eww-bookmark-handler)))

(defun oht-eww-set-bookmark-handler ()
  "Set local variable to call function to save eww bookmark"
  (interactive)
  (set (make-local-variable 'bookmark-make-record-function)
       #'oht-eww-bookmark-make-record))

(defun oht-eww-bookmark-handler (record)
  "Jump to an eww bookmarked location."
  (eww (bookmark-prop-get record 'location)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I just got the syntax wrong for the `oht-eww-bookmark-make-record` function. The below is a complete working solution.

```lisp
(defun oht-eww-current-title ()
  "Returns the title of the current eww buffer"
  (plist-get eww-data :title))

(defun oht-eww-bookmark-make-record ()
  "Return a bookmark record for the current eww buffer."
  (interactive)
  `(,(oht-eww-current-title)
    (location . ,(eww-current-url))
    (handler . oht-eww-bookmark-handler)))

(defun oht-eww-set-bookmark-handler ()
  "This tells Emacs which function to use to create bookmarks."
  (interactive)
  (set (make-local-variable 'bookmark-make-record-function)
       #'oht-eww-bookmark-make-record))

(defun oht-eww-bookmark-handler (record)
  "Jump to an eww bookmarked location."
  (eww (bookmark-prop-get record 'location)))

(add-hook 'eww-mode-hook 'oht-eww-set-bookmark-handler)
```

Comment: Hello,
i tried your snippet.
But nothing happens, no error, no bookmark.
Saving a bookmark inside eww saves it to the eww bookmark list.
Or do i not understand your effort?
Please explain a little bit more.

Thanks
Poul

Comment: This allows you to use `bookmark-set` on webpages in eww. You can view them with `list-bookmarks`. These bookmarks are different from eww's bookmarks.

Comment: thank you for the clear answer. I thought, that the eww bookmark command is modified by this code.
Now i try C-x r m or M and it works great!
Thanks a lot.
Regards